# How do I replace all data rows grouped by specific conditions when the data has more rows than the replacement?

Tags: r

dput( DATE     SITE CODE   D1   D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7  D8  D9  H   RowTotal
    1  2019-07-03   JUP AAGA    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   15  16
    2   2019-07-03  JUP EFAS    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
    3   2019-07-03  JUP MANG    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
    4   2019-07-03  JUP MCAV    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   128 128
    5   2019-07-03  JUP MDEC    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
    6   2019-07-03  JUP MMEA    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
    7   2019-07-03  JUP OANN    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2
    8   2019-07-03  JUP PAST    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   17  17
    9   2019-07-03  JUP SBOU    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2
    10  2019-07-03  JUP SINT    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9   9
    11  2019-07-03  JUP SRAD    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
    12  2019-07-03  JUP SSID    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   5
    13  2019-07-19  SLR ISIN    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
    14  2019-07-19  SLR MCAV    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   2
    16  2019-07-19  SLR PCLI    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   5   7
    17  2019-07-19  SLR SBOU    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
    18  2019-07-19  SLR SSID    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   8   9
    19  2019-07-26  PMP AAGA    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   7
    20  2019-07-26  PMP ACER    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   57  57
    21  2019-07-26  PMP CNAT    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
    22  2019-07-26  PMP DSTO    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   2
    23  2019-07-26  PMP MAUR    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   14  14
    24  2019-07-26  PMP MCAV    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   14  285 299)

This is my dataset. I am trying to add a new column with `SiteTotal` by adding the `RowTotals` that meet the same `Date` and `Site` conditions. I have tried multiple things in `dplyr`: `group_by`, `summarize`, etc. I keep running into the issue of the replacement being a less number of rows than the dataset. For example with `group_by(Date, Site, RowTotal)` for this data set we would replacement of 3 but there are 24 rows. Is there a way for each row to be filled that meet the conditions. My end goals is to find the "code" prevalence for each site at the specific date.

The expected column that I want would be SiteTotal shown below:

(184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 184, 429, 429, 429, 429, 429, 429, 81, 81, 81, 81, 81)

The end goal would to take my RowTotal column and divid it by my SiteTotal column to find "code prevalence" at the specific date and site.

Comment: Please show the expected

Comment: Is this as simple as `df1 %>% group_by(DATE, SITE) %>% summarise(SiteTotal = sum(RowTotal))`?

Comment: Can you use `dput()` around your data you are trying to use and then copy and paste the output for us? It makes the code needed to replicate your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mutate to add a column

`df1 %>% group_by(DATE, SITE) %>% mutate(SiteTotal = sum(RowTotal))`

Comment: Now I am having difficulties adding another column for CodePrevalence: I have tried: dput( df1$CodePrevalence = df1$RowTotal/df1$SiteTotal) and get the error message: replacement has 0 rows, data has 24...       I also tried dput( df1$Codeprevalence <- df1[[RowTotal]]/df1[[SiteTotal]] ) and receive the error that object 'RowTotal'is not found

Comment: dput is not used in normal r code, dput only prints out the structure of the data, I can modify the r code, use `mutate(Codeprevalence  = RowTotal/SiteTotal)`

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure, and awesome that worked!!